# Complex MySQL five table join

Tags: mysql, join

I have following five table:

**Table name:      Fields**

**dba_acc:**          account_id, username
**user_inst:**        account_id, instance_name, host_name
**instances:**       instance_key, instance_name
**db_inst:**           db_key, instance_key
**dbs:**                 db, db_key

All the tables are inter connected.

I want to develop a query that displays account_id, username, instance_name, host_name, and db of a specific user.

For example, if I select username = 'Joe' then it should display account_id of 'Joe', instance_name and host_name that are related to 'Joe', and db related to each instance_name.

Relation between instance_name and host_name is many to many.

It is so complicated. I am stuck! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think the complex tag applies here

Comment: "I want to develop" -- so what's stopping you from doing it? What have you tried that hasn't worked? Removed the `complex` tag as this is very routine.

Comment: This shouldn't be downvoted, guys.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ::

```
Select dba_acc.account_id, dba_acc.username, user_inst.instance_name ,
user_inst.host_name, instances.instance_key, dbs.db
from 
dba_acc
inner join   user_inston on (dba_acc.account_id =user_inston.account_id)
inner join instances on (instances.instance_name = user_inst.instance_name)
inner join db_inst on (db_inst.instance_key = instances.instance_key)
inner join dbs on (dbs.db_key = db_inst.db_key)
```

Comment: Thanks Sashi I am gonna try it now!

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from
dba_acc a
join user_inst u on a.account_id u.account_id
join instances i on u.instance_name = i.instance_name
join db_inst db on i.instanec_key = db.instance_key
join dbs on db.db_key = dbs.db_key
```

It is just like wiring. Look for the common columns by name and keep joining.